# Refrigerator rust spots paint touchup

Tags: painting, paint, appliances, refrigerator, rust-removal

My refrigerator door has developed a few little spots where rust has bubbled up and the paint has flaked off. Mostly under 5mm in diameter, but a couple along the edges and corners of the door are longer. It's an older model (GE TBX18, over 20 years old) but it's running fine and I'd like to fix these small cosmetic issues before they grow.

I found a few products for touching up white appliances. Whirlpool makes a paint, while Rust-Oleum has an epoxy. Neither one mentions what to do about rust before painting though. The spots are small and flush with the paint, which will make sanding difficult.

What is the recommended procedure for fixing very small rust spots on a refrigerator?